# How to force a known PIN code based Pairing using SSP?

Tags: bluetooth, pairing, speaker, ssp

**Objective:** We are developing a smart speaker tailored for the hospitality industry. In hotel rooms, guests are permitted to connect their smartphones via Bluetooth to the speaker and play their preferred music. Our task is to implement a secure pairing mechanism to ensure that only the registered guest, who is staying in that particular room, can pair their device with the speaker. Unauthorized access should be prevented.
Please note the Smart Speaker is headless ,doesn't have "Display"

The option put across to us from customer is, On check-in guest will be provided with a PIN, they need to enter this PIN in Smart phone for pairing the speaker.
Is this possible to achieve using SSP pairing?
One typical question is if there is any way to force a known PIN code for pairing in general. Unfortunately ,as we understand, with SSP there is no way to do that according to the specification, except if you configure the smart phone to key board only capability, that is up to the smart phone manufacturer and we cannot control it.

This was allowed in legacy pairing, but this is no longer an option for BT devices following core specification 2.1 and above.

Now, how can we achieve this? I am sure this will be use case for many others in industry and BT will be supporting this one or other way, Can you please help us here?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do almost the same thing, ESP32 bluetooth SPP+SSP and i want to pass a password (pin code or passkey) from my phone to pair to ESP32 device. the only way i'm able to do that is to disable SSP. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

> One typical question is if there is any way to force a known PIN code for pairing in general.

> This was allowed in legacy pairing, but this is no longer an option for BT devices following core specification 2.1 and above.

Yes, you are right, a much simpler way to achieve this is using BR/EDR legacy pairing, in which case you can control which PIN code to use on the speaker.

If you can modify the firmware on the speaker, you can enforce legacy pairing
using `HCI_Write_Simple_Pairing_Mode` HCI command (see BLUETOOTH CORE SPECIFICATION Version 5.4 | Vol 4, Part E, 7.3.59 Write Simple Pairing Mode command)

> Is this possible to achieve using SSP pairing?

A potential problem with legacy pairing is security. Using SSP is not impossible. An option to think about is OOB pairing.

But in either case, you need to modify the firmware.